# Is it possible from WCF client to get the service IP behind a load balancer?

Tags: c#, wcf, load-balancing

I know some ways to get the client IP from a WCF service, but I'm not able to get the server IP.

I can make some changes in the service, so it would be able to return the IP address, but I'm trying to do this without modify the service.

**My scenario:**
I call a service by a dns, that runs in  a load balance (e.g. services.company.com, that  resolves to 192.168.0.1), so I cannot know which server is responding the request (192.168.0.10 or 192.168.0.11).

[image]

For log purpose, I would like to know which server processed my request.

I think that probably it's not possible, but who knows can anyone help me or give a clue?

Comment: If you own the WCF service, you can let it insert either IP or host name in the response header. If you don't own that, there is no way to do so.

Comment: @LexLi thank you. Yes, I thought that, probably only the service can send this information, but I had a hope that could be some way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I thought, I could not find any way to get the IP from a server without make changes in server side.
But I've tried to hit the goal without modifying all services, and I ended up with this approach:

https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpprotocol/customheaders

I added a **custom header** to my IIS Server, so when I consume a service, the server add a value to the header, that I can recover in client.
Basically you can add a custom header in IIS Manager, or you can add to the configuration file, adding those lines to `system.webServer` node:

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-ServerName" value="myServerNameOrIP" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

It can be done at server level or to some application in particular. This solved the issue.

Of course, I'm putting this only in internal servers, I don't want my external clients receiving this information.